# NullPointer in Kotlin Synthetics for some views with Jetpack Compose Integration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to integrate the new jetpack compose in my existing app . My app is right now dependent on kotlin synthetics. When I tried to integrate compose , I am getting `NullPointerException` in some Kotlin synthetics while trying to access views. Here is my code

```
    internal const val compose = "1.0.0-beta07"
    internal const val activityCompose = "1.3.0-alpha03"
    internal const val kotlinVersion = "1.4.32"
```

```
kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "${Versions.kotlinVersion}"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "${Versions.compose}"
    }
```

```
    const val composeUI = "androidx.compose.ui:ui:${Versions.compose}"

    const val activityCompose = "androidx.activity:activity-compose:${Versions.activityCompose}"
    const val materialCompose = "androidx.compose.material:material:${Versions.compose}"
    const val toolingCompose = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:${Versions.compose}"
```

But when I remove below Code it works well. Also I tried with view binding it is working fine.

```
 buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: Not sure about the issue but  kotlin synthetics is deprecated the property type  kotlin synthetics uses is platform type its not nullable that's why it can produce NPE . i myself faced some weird NPE even inside the lifecycle of the component's view . so i think you should move on with View binding .

Comment: Yes I know it is deprecated but I can't move all my code to view binding at once .  Can't we use both compose and synthetics together ?

Comment: @FiXiT No, as said, it is deprecated and you should move to view binding.